# Web Scraping 101

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, http-status-code-404

I'm doing a simple web scrape that prints the price of a company's stock based on the entered ticker symbol. I was able to do this for many companies like SBUX, UPS, NKE, AAPL, BRK-A, and BRK-B. However, I tried MOTR.L, and I got the following error. AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'. In the below code, I simply printed the HTML from beautiful soup, and it was obvious the HTML from the website and beautiful soup are not the same. When I print the source variable, I get a response 404, which I assume is an invalid URL. When I print the source variable for the companies that worked, I get a response 200. Could it be the '.' in the ticker symbol that is causing the issue?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

Ticker = "MOTR.L"
source = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + Ticker).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

price = soup.find("fin-streamer", {"class": "Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)"}).text

print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: there is no company with "MOTR.L" stock symbol

Comment: Would you try to mock up the request header as your browser does?

Answer (score 1):

Added the User-Agent in the request header, and it works!!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

Ticker = "MOTR.L"
source = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + Ticker, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7)"}).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

price = soup.find("fin-streamer", {"data-field": "regularMarketPrice"}).text

print(price)
```

Comment: Awesome! I have heard mentions of (User-Agent) headers, but didn't really understand why they're necessary to use. After doing some reading, it makes sense. Thanks for the help! Also, there are other fields on the webpage that use 'regularMarketPrice'. To only include the price of the company I'm attempting to look up, I'll unfortunately have to stick with searching for the specific class.